# Dual-boot Mint on OS X: is OS X Startup Manager not suitable to boot Mint partition?

Tags: linux-mint, osx, dual-boot

I am thinking of dual-booting Linux Mint on Mac OS X, and for that reason I was reading a tutorial about it (http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1643).

After Mint's installation the tutorial focuses on changing the boot order (because OS X would be booted first by default) to make the system boot into Grub . I was wondering if this step is necessary, considering I would run Linux occasionally, while using mostly OS X.

Can't I just use OS X boot manager (holding the option key at start-up) to choose the Mint partition when I want to use it? Would there be side effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i'm not an apple-user (maybe the guys at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ know it better) i'm not sure about the OS X boot manager, but some time ago i read it's not a real boot manager because it's really stripped down... thats why [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) and it's successor [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) was created!

---

to make it really easy:
i would recommend to follow ["your" tutorial](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1643) (it's written by the lead-developer of Linux Mint), use [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) and just change the bootorder to your needs... so the last command (according to the tutorial) would be `sudo efibootmgr -o 80,0`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this solves the practical part of my question. I'll try asking in the apple stackexchange for the details of OS X boot manager.